# My script misses lines while reading a file

Tags: perl, file, file-handling

I'm doing a large (8000 lines) library data conversion. I read in a file and want to modify it line by line. Reading the file stops before reaching the end of the file.

```
open(my $infh, "<", 'infile.pica') 
        || die('Could not open pica file'); 
open(my $outfh, ">", 'infile.pica.norm') 
        || die('Could not open pica file');

my $counter = 0;

while (my $line = <$infh>) {

    $counter++;
    # for debugging - this is the last line being read. 
    # infile actually has 7857 lines

    if ($counter >= 7691) {
        say $line;
    }
    # modification commented out for debugging
    print $outfh $line;
}   
close $infh;
close $outfh;
```

My first thought was that there is a strange character in this line but there is nothing

```
006X $cEBC$03564211 (original)
006X $cEBC$035642 (being read, thats what the say prints)
```

Here is a snippet of the dataset where it stops reading:

```
002@ $0Oax
002C $aText$btxt
002D $aComputermedien$bc
002E $aOnline-Ressource$bcr
004A $09780309160193
006X $cEBC$03564211
010@ $aeng
011@ $a2010
```

You can see every line is followed by a line-break 
(Hey code `0A`). The line 006X is where it stops reading.

Comment: Your code looks ok, maybe post some more details of your setup?

Comment: Have you looked at the last character(s) on the lines? By default, Perl will split lines on a newline character (`\n`) - do all of your lines have one?

Comment: you can open the file in something like notepad++, make it show all characters (like CR, LF etc..) and look at the suspect line, there may indeed be something there that you cant "see"

Comment: If looked at the hey dump of the input file. Every line has an `A0`at the end.

Comment: Based on [your answer below](https:///stackoverflow.com/a/45547075/100754), the code you posted in your question had nothing whatsoever to do with your problem, and it is obvious it did not generate the output you claimed it did. It is not a good idea to *purposefully* ***lie*** to people whom you are asking for help. Also, don't post screenshots of text. I showed you how to get a hex dump. Post that.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution: The problem had nothing to do with the script I posted or even reading from files. In the script I did not post, I was forgetting to flush the output by calling:

```
PICA::Writer->end()
```

See [PICA::Writer->end](https://metacpan.org/pod/PICA::Writer#end-(-)):

> Finish writing. Depending on the format and output handler a footer is written (for instance an XML end tag) and the output handler is closed. Afterwards the status is set to `PICA::Writer::ENDED`. If the writer had not been started before, the start method is called first.
>
> Ending or writing to an already ended writer will throw an error. You can restart an ended writer with the output method or with the start method.